# Implementing an appBar immediately crashes the flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Simple code in flutter but I always get this ERROR:

```
E/flutter (22965): [ERROR:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontFamily.cpp(184)] Could not get cmap table size!
E/flutter (22965): 
F/flutter (22965): [FATAL:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontCollection.cpp(95)] nTypefaces == 0
F/libc    (22965): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 23003 (Thread-2), pid 22965
```

i already read about having troubles with fonts causing this error, but I have no whitespacing in my names

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some mistakes, for example: placing the appBar in the bottomNavigationBar... but, I think that should solve it:

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```